# How to turn off last modify in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

i pressed something and now this is shown in intelij idea, how do i turn this off. Probably,i pressed some key combination but now i cant find this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hidee this info by disabling **View | Appearance | Descriptions in Tree Views**